# Casting "bigger" objects into "smaller" objects in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm having troubles with assigning bigger objects into smaller objects. But I think I can best describe it with a simple example:

Suppose I have declared the Typescript interface:

```
export interface CrewMember {
   name: string;
   organizing_function?: string;
 }
```

I now retrieve from a database an array of objects like this:

```
[{
 id: "someID",
 name: "Jack"
},{
 id: "someOtherID",
 name: "Jipp",
 organizing_function: "Being good at stuff"
}]
```

I want to create an Array< CrewMember > wherein to put the objects from the database. However, my problem is that the the objects from the database have an "ID" which "CrewMember" doesn't. Hence I cannot simply assign them because Typescript complains that the types are incompatible.

I first tried something like this:

```
let crewmember : CrewMember = {
 name: database[0].name,
 organizing_function: database[0].organizing_function
};
```

However this is (1) quite the amount of work as I have many different types that are much, much bigger than this and (2) difficult because organizing_function is an optional parameter. So, as I understand, I would have to write a ton of "IF" clauses to find out what properties are given or not on the database object and then assign correctly.

**So what is the best way to approach "casting" an object with superfluous properties into another object with a lot of optional properties in Typescript?**

Would really appreciate any help on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this actually a problem when you're fetching data from a database, rather than assigning literals? The error I'd expect is `Object literal may only specify known properties`, which you *wouldn't* get if they were coming from elsewhere at runtime.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. *a database an array of objects like this* - and these objects are compatible with CrewMember. As it was said, TS is unaware which type you're getting from database. You should state it, and the problem is probably because you didn't do this properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript is just a compile-time tool: in the end everything is javascript and nothing is typed.

So what you call casting is different from, for example, what is called casting in Java (where a runtime check is done).
In typescript you can write:

```
const a: { prop: string } = (4 as any)
```

and it won't be a problem at all, don't use it as a `{ prop: string }`, it will fail, but the casting itself will be ok.

Now, if you retrieved a javascript object named `data` of type `{ id: string; name: string; organizing_function: string}[]` from somewhere, you can write:

```
const members: CrewMember[] = data;
```

And that's all.